# How to count members with a specified subclass from a List?

Tags: c#

I have an `Enemy` class.

There are classes that inherit from it, like `Soldier`, `Captain`, and so on.

I have a List that contains all enemies.

If I wanted to count how many are of type `Soldier`, I could do:

```
List<Enemy> enemies;

public int CountSoldiers()
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
    {
        if (enemy is Soldier)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

But there are many types of enemies, and I would like to count by any type. Is there a way to pass an enemy or its type as a parameter so it is counted?

That would be an example code, but it does NOT work:

```
public int CountEnemyType(System.Type type)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
    {
        if (enemy is type)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
public int CountEnemiesByType<T>()  where T : Enemy
{
    return enemies.OfType<T>().Count();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int soldierCount = CountEnemiesByType<Soldier>();
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/eEeElR

I'm also inclined to build it more like this:

```
public int CountEnemiesByType<T>(IEnumerable<Enemy> enemies)  where T : Enemy
{
    return enemies.OfType<T>().Count();
}
```

But even more this seems like something where we should be using composition instead of inheritance: an enemy has a type, rather than is a type.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach without the need to define any additional methods:

```
var soldierCount = enemies.Count(e => e is Soldier);
```